# browser compatibility test with Firefox

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I want to check my web project in various browsers. In IE 10, I have options `Browse Mode : Compatibility` (IE8,IE9,IE10). same testing in firefox I have to install the browser separately. I knew there is option to check `http://browsershots.org/` like this sites. but I want to check individually.

Requirement:

```
I'm having firefox v27 but I want to test with firefox v19 without uninstalling or without  use any portable version or  don't use online testing websites. is any possibility?
```

Comment: if you don't want to online check than there are no way to check it in local without uninstalling and installing version.

check it https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967855

Comment: k. i agree. could i know the reason of negative mark. i searched through net, i couldn't find any option only that i posted this question.

Comment: I not gives you negative mark.

Comment: thanks jay. i hope the question is right. isn't it

Comment: yes but you can search from net first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "not-online" cross browser testing solution like www.browseemall.com or if you prefer a online solution maybe something like www.browserling.com ?